# GC overhead limit exceeded when enable R8 Shrinker in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-r8, android-studio-3.4

I'm using Android Studio 3.4 (Canary 9), when I build my app, it failed with the following error

> Task :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForDebug
>
> R8 is an
>   experimental feature. If you experience any issues, please file a bug
>   at https://issuetracker.google.com, using 'Shrinker (R8)' as component
>   name. You can disable R8 by updating gradle.properties with
>   'android.enableR8=false'.
>
> AGPBI: {"kind":"warning","text":"Missing class:
>   java.lang.instrument.ClassFileTransformer","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
>
> Task :app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForDebug FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithR8ForDebug'.
>
> GC overhead limit exceeded

When I disable R8 by putting `android.enableR8=false` into **gradle.properties**. Everything is working fine.

So how can I fix this error without disable R8 Shrinker? Because I'm really want to test functionality of R8.

Comment: Do you have a particular setting for `org.gradle.jvmargs` or do you use defaults?

Comment: In my AS 3.3 R8 works fine.

Comment: @shadowsheep yes it worked on AS 3.3, but when I upgrade, it no longer working. Btw I'm not using any custom jvm args

Comment: So, try tweaking memory settings like that `org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=1024m -Xmx4608M` for example, or more. Let's see if it solves. Let me know.

Comment: @nhoxbypass im getting the same gc overhead error. have you found a fix for this?

Answer (score 49):

As you said you are not using any custom `JVM args`, try it out.

In your `gradle.properties` file try several values for [memory settings](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:configuring_jvm_memory). For example try to set

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m
```

As suggested by the commented section:

> Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
>
> The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
>
> org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m

I've used R8 in my project and all worked fine.

Comment: With gradle version 5.1.1 (in gradle-wrapper.properties) this not working (nor with set heap size and Xmx to 4 GB), but with actual 5.4.1 version do working (also with only sets Xmx to 2 GB).

Comment: Make sure to use **gradle.properties** not gradle-wrapper.properties

Comment: Working for me with Android Studio 3.5.2. This also increased the speed of my builds in general.

Comment: Doesn't work for when building on Jenkins with com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1

Comment: the only thing that worked for me, finally... Thanks a lot for saving my day

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes adding JVM heap memory does not solve the problem especially on systems that have limited memory, it will cause other problems. my recommendation is to try replacing the Garbage Collector.

`org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC`

GC overhead limit exceeded is an exception throw by default java 8 garbage collector (Parallel). In my case, it solved the problems.