# How to solve outofmemory error during android build?

Tags: android

I have problem with compile android application.

This is my error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

and

```
> com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to complete
```

I set javaMaxHeapSize to maximum:

```
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
```

Project is compiling but even then after one hour it goes with errors.

How could I solve this issue?

Comment: increase your pc virtual memory

Comment: I am not sure if the `dexOptions` are used at all in modern Andorid gradle plugin versions because `dex`is no longer used (r8 is now used). But increasing the gradle heap in general should work: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56420408/150978